# How to return columns from nested SELECT queries in the final table?

Tags: sql, join, hana

I have three layered nested query which works.

```sql
select PARTNER, BIRTHDT, XSEXM, XSEXF from "schema"."platform.view/table2" where partner IN 
(select SID from "schema"."platform.view/table1" where TYPE='BB' and CLASS='yy' and ID IN 
(select SID from "schema"."platform.view/table1" where TYPE='AA' and CLASS='zz' and ID IN ("one", "two")
))
```

I want the values ( "one", "two") from table1 in the inner most query to be present in the final Table returned.

I have tried to get it like this:

```sql
select t1.ID, t2.SID from "schema"."platform.view/table1" t1
OUTER APPLY (
select SID from "schema"."platform.view/table1" t2
where t2.TYPE='BB' and t2.CLASS='yy' and t2.ID IN t1.SID
)
where t1.TYPE='AA' and t1.CLASS='zz' and t1.ID IN ("one", "two")
```

There are three three identifiers:
1. `ID` ( ONE, TWO, etc.)
2. intermediate SID ( 123, 124, etc) which is again searched as ID
3. Partner ID (P12, P13, etc) which maps to table2.

### Sample Data:

table1:

```
| ID   | SID | TYPE | CLASS |
|------|-----|------|-------|
| ONE  | 123 | AA   | zz    |
| TWO  | 124 | AA   | zz    |
| 123  | P12 | BB   | yy    |
| THRE | 125 | AA   | zz    |
| 124  | P13 | BB   | yy    |
| 125  | P14 | BB   | yy    |
| FOUR | 123 | AA   | zz    |
```

table2:

```
| PARTNER | BIRTHDT  | XSEXM | XSEXF |
|---------|----------|-------|-------|
| P12     | 19900214 | X     |       |
| P13     | 19900713 | X     |       |
| P14     | 19900407 |       | X     |
```

Desired Output for Input `("ONE", "TWO", "THRE")`:

```
| ID  | PARTNER | BIRTHDT  | XSEXM | XSEXF |
|-----|---------|----------|-------|-------|
| ONE | P12     | 19900214 | X     |       |
| TWO | P13     | 19900713 | X     |       |
| THRE| P14     | 19900407 |       | X     |
```

How to map this initial search value with its final result rows in this three layer nested statement?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really clarify your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Essentially I want to `map` the result table with the original column used as input. i.e., the details with the original ID.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to "carry" information from your "inner" `SELECT`s you can either "join back" the data at the final projection step which requires that you have a 1:1 relationship that you could use for the join.

This is not the case here.

Instead, don't use the `WHERE ... IN (SELECT ID...)` approach, but `INNER JOIN`s instead.
These allow the same kind of filtering/selection but also give the option to project any column of the two involved tables.

For your rather abstract statement (the column names really need a lot of context knowledge in order to make sense... - that's something you may want to fix by adding useful column aliases) this can look like so:

```
drop table tab1;
drop table tab2;

CREATE TABLE TAB1
    ("ID" varchar(6)
    , "SID" varchar(5)
    , "TYPE" varchar(6)
    , "CLASS" varchar(7))
;


 INSERT   INTO TAB1 
         VALUES ('ONE', '123', 'AA', 'zz');
 INSERT   INTO TAB1  
         VALUES ('TWO', '124', 'AA', 'zz');
 INSERT   INTO TAB1  
         VALUES ('123', 'P12', 'BB', 'yy');
 INSERT   INTO TAB1 
         VALUES ('THRE', '125', 'AA', 'zz');
 INSERT   INTO TAB1 
         VALUES ('124', 'P13', 'BB', 'yy');
 INSERT   INTO TAB1  
         VALUES ('125', 'P14', 'BB', 'yy');
  INSERT  INTO TAB1  
         VALUES ('FOUR', '123', 'AA', 'zz');


 select * from tab1;
 CREATE TABLE TAB2
    ("PARTNER" varchar(9)
    , "BIRTHDT" varchar(10)
    , "XSEXM" varchar(7)
    , "XSEXF" varchar(7))
;

INSERT    INTO TAB2
         VALUES ('P12', '19900214', 'X', NULL);
INSERT    INTO TAB2
         VALUES ('P13', '19900713', 'X', NULL);
INSERT    INTO TAB2
         VALUES ('P14', '19900407', NULL, 'X');
with id_sel as (
    select SID, ID 
      from TAB1 
      where 
            TYPE='AA' 
        and CLASS='zz' 
        and ID IN ('ONE', 'TWO', 'THRE')
),
part_sel as (
    select 
        t1.SID, id.ID orig_id 
    from 
        TAB1 t1
        inner join id_sel id
            on t1.id = id.sid

    where 
             t1.TYPE='BB' 
        and  t1.CLASS='yy' 

)           
select 
        part_sel.orig_id, t2.PARTNER, t2.BIRTHDT, t2.XSEXM, t2.XSEXF 
from 
    TAB2 t2
    inner join part_sel
     on t2.partner = part_sel.sid;



ORIG_ID PARTNER BIRTHDT     XSEXM   XSEXF
ONE     P12     19900214    X       ?    
TWO     P13     19900713    X       ?    
THRE    P14     19900407    ?       X
```